# Matplotlib contour plot with nonuniform, matrix grids

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to contour plot a function, f(x,y), against x and x-y. The spacing in the y grid is not the same as the x grid, so x-y is 2 dimensional, whereas x is one-dimensional.

I do not know how to set up the grids. The function, `tricontourf`, can handle non-uniform grids, but only it seems, if both the axes are one-dimensional. `contour` can handle matrices, but only for f(x,y), whereas I need one of the axes to be a matrix.

Pseudocode would look like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def twoDfunction(x,y):
   return x + y # my function is more complicated than this

xaxis = np.linspace(0,10,100)
yaxis = np.linspace(0,10,22)
xminusyaxis = np.subtract(xaxis,yaxis)
functionsurfacevalues = twoDfunction(xaxis,yaxis)

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=300,facecolor='w')
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.tricontourf(xaxis, xminusyaxis, functionsurfacevalues)
```

I would like the pseudocode to plot `functionsurfacevalues` versus `x` and `xminusy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create your grid using `np.meshgrid()` and then plot a `contour` or `contourf` plot.`np.meshgrid` will make irregular grids based on whatever you give it. You do not need a surface plot because your data isn't really a surface.

The main problem you are having is that because your x and y axis are different lengths, you can't subtract them. Otherwise the solution is easy and you can follow the following code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def twoDfunction(x,y):
   return (x + y) # my function is more complicated than this

xaxis = np.linspace(0,10,100)
yaxis = np.linspace(0,5,100)

xminusyaxis = np.subtract(xaxis,yaxis)

xx,yy = np.meshgrid(xaxis,xminusyaxis)

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=300,facecolor='w')
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.contourf(xx, yy, twoDfunction(xx,yy))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How do I use Contourf when xminusy is a matrix rather than a vector? So far, `surface_plot` works, but it's not elegant.

Comment: Im confused about how you get a matrix from a subtracting 2 vectors?

Comment: I was not clear. For a given y, the xminusy grid will be shifted by y. Thus, if there are N y points and M x points, the xminusy grid will be N X M in size.